# Fiware timestamp avoid numeric rounding

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am trying to save metadata of timestamp type and it automatically rounds, how can I avoid this rounding?

ex:

original post:

```
{  
   "2":{  
      "type":"float",
      "value":25.7,
      "metadata":{  
         "timestamp":{  
            "value":1535437067,
            "type":"Number"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer Get:

```
"2": {
         "type": "float",
         "value": 25.7,
         "metadata": {
             "timestamp": {
                 "type": "Number",
                 "value": 1535440000
             }
         }
     }
```

Round: 1535437067 to 1535440000. How can I leave it unrounded?

A greeting.

Comment: Could you edit your question post to include the Orion version you are using, please? `curl /version` or `contextBroker --version` would provide that information. Thanks!

Comment: {
    "orion": {
        "version": "1.10.0-next",
        "uptime": "35 d, 2 h, 35 m, 0 s",
        "git_hash": "569ad4fa33573e0d3e87abfd900dc2396bfe2230",
        "compile_time": "Thu Feb 1 11:44:14 CET 2018",

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem was solved in Orion 1.15.0. From the [release notes of that version](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/1.15.0):

> Fix: large integer wrong rendering in responses ([#2603](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2603))

Thus, if you upgrate from 1.10.0-next to 1.15.0 or newer you would get the fix.